# String image reference from DB into ImageView background

Tags: android

I'm storing on database references to images like this value

`android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@9d0968b0`

Now im trying to get that image reference in a `ImageView` as background.

How can i set the background of `myImageView` with that `String` reference?

How i do something like

`myImageView.setBackground(//android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@9d0968b0);`

Comment: This won't work because you can't get an object by using it's reference id. Where is the image itself being stored? In your `res/drawable` folder? Assets folder? Online?

Comment: yes @OmarSilva res/drawable. Im saving the reference like this `String imgRef07 = imgC7.getBackground().toString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because you can't get an object by using it's reference id.

If the image whose id you're trying to save resides inside your `res/drawable` folder, then the simplest solution is to save your image's resource entry name, like so:

```
String resourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.your_image_name);
// Save resourceName to database.
```

Then later retrieve it:

```
int resourceId = getResources()
           .getIdentifier(<resource_name_from_database>, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

And finally, set your `ImageView`'s background like this:

```
Drawable myDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), resourceId, null);
myImageView.setBackground(myDrawable);
```